# designing the predicate for the filter function

Tags: python, recursion, filter, higher-order-functions

I have this in built filter function for my homework.

```
def filter(pred, seq):
    if seq == ():
        return ()
    elif pred(seq[0]):
        return (seq[0],) filter(pred, seq[1:])
    else:
        return filter(pred, seq[1:])
```

We are supposed to convert a give function to one that has only one return line using the designed filter function (which overwrites the more powerful python version).

The code that we are supposed to convert is this:

```
def lookup_bus_stop_by_road(stops, road):
    matched = ()
    for bus_stop in stops:
        if get_road_name(bus_stop) == road:
            matched = matched + (bus_stop, )
    return matched
```

my question is: how am i supposed to convert the predicate for my filter function by adapting from the given lookup_bus_Stop_by_road function? But I have always got the TypeError: bool object not callable.

This is the return line i have put in:

```
def lookup_bus_stop_by_road(stops, road):
    return filter(get_road_name(bus_stops) == road, stops)
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
get_road_name(bus_stops) == road
```

is a boolean value, not a function.  What you want to do is create a function that calls `get_road_name` and checks if the result is equal to `road`

```
filter(lambda x: get_road_name(x) == road, stops)
```

For more reading on this topic see here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Comment: Alright thank you so much! initially i used something like lambda x: road == x[1]. The idea you suggested prevents me from breaking the abstraction